# Vislization Software for Live Audio?

Tags: audio, music

Currently I have been using WinAmp, with MilkDrop visulization plugins to disply visulizations that go with the music. This works fine for normal music files, but now I am in a situation where I require visulizations for a live audio in feed.

Is there currently any software out there that can be used to show visulizations for live audio, or even if nothing good exists, is there anyway to still use WinAmp for live audio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play audio from line input on your sound card in winamp using a line in plugin or as the Milkdrop wiki page states:

> 3. TELL WINAMP TO USE LINE-IN
>       Open Winamp, and hit CTRL+L (the "Open Location" hotkey).  Now
>       type in "linein://" as the location you want to open.  (Leave out
>       the quotes and make sure you use FORWARD slashes.)  Hit PLAY
>       ('x' key for the lazy), and the little built-in oscilloscope (or
>       spectrum analyzer) in Winamp should start showing your signal.

*[Source](http://wiki.winamp.com/wiki/MilkDrop_Unleashed_Guide)*

The R4 plugin  by rabidhamster can be an interesting choice as well.

Comment: This solves my issue, enjoy the +50 rep!